# There is a number if you multiply it by 6 first, and then subtract 7 from the result, you get 65. what's the number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I've been stuck on this question for a while can someone help me thanks :)

Comment: 65 + 7 = 72. 72/6 = 12. Reverse the operations they gave you.

Comment: Call the number $x$. Translate the information into an equation in $x$. Solve the equation.

Comment: Incidentally, in problems like this, if you get stuck, I recommend guessing.  Obviously, it won't always solve the problem quickly, but you may get better insight into how to attack similar problems than if you just looked up how to do it.

Comment: @BrianTung: That is terrible advice! This problem is a perfect introduction to the solution of simple equations using algebra. If you solve it by trial and error, you won't learn anything at all. And if you try to solve it by trial and error, and fail, it seems to me that you will learn less than nothing. So a lose-lose scenario.

Comment: I disagree, obviously.  If you just guess, and all you care about is whether you got the right answer, then yes, you are right: You don't learn anything at all.  But I argue that someone who would be so remarkably uncurious as all that would never learn anything from *any* technique.  They would only learn an isolated technique for solving *one* kind of problem, which is hardly any improvement at all.  If you have any innate curiosity at all, you will learn from your failed attempts at guessing what analysis needs to be performed to arrive at the answer, better than if you had been told.

Comment: I suppose that I should preface my advice with, "If you are truly curious about learning how to proceed"—but I think that any such condition will be lost on those to whom it does not apply.  I'm not really concerned about them; they're happy not knowing.

Answer (score 6):

1. Let $x$ equal your unknown number.
2. Apply the operations you are given in order:
   $$6x - 7 = 65$$
3. Solve for $x$ and you get your number:
   $$6x = 65 + 7$$
   $$ 6x = 72$$
   $$ x = 72/6$$
   $$ x= 12$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{There is a number}&n\\
\text{if you multiply it by 6 first}&6n\\
\text{and then subtract 7 from the result}&6n-7\\
\text{you get 65}&6n-7=65
\end{array}$$

Can you take it from here?